# Squared Modal Pop-up LWC

Tags: lightning-modal

I have the below modal pop-up built using LWC that has curvy edges but I need the edges to be squared.

Actual :
[image]

Expected :

[image]

Here's the modal pop-up piece of HTML code for the existing one :
I want to achieve this without making major changes in the below code

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Contrary to the first comment, I find your question very clear. But please don't present source code via a screenshot. This makes it much more time consuming to experiment with your input; it's also bad for search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border radius is coming from `slds-modal__header` and `slds-modal__footer`.
You can either add a class and specify styles with more specificity or the lightning design system has [styling hooks for slds-modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/#Styling-Hooks-Overview). You can override the hook to eliminate those border radius.

add this to your .css file of the lwc:

```
.slds-modal__header, .slds-modal__footer{
   --slds-c-modal-radius-border: 0;
}
```